# Using setExpires on returnJson

Tags: plugin-development, cache, json

From a custom plugin controller, I am returning data as json using [`$this->returnJson($data)`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/BaseController#returnJson-detail). I need to be able to set the Cache-Control headers for my forward cache proxy to handle caching correctly.

I tried using [`HeaderHelper::setExpires(300)`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/HeaderHelper#setExpires-detail), but [`JsonHelper::sendJsonHeaders()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/JsonHelper#sendJsonHeaders-detail), which is called by [`$this->returnJson()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/BaseController#returnJson-detail) from the controller, overrides `setExpires` by calling [`HeaderHelper::setNoCache()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/HeaderHelper#setNoCache-detail).

Does anyone have any ideas for working around this or configuring `returnJson`? I can do the following in my controller (or create a helper of my own):

```
HeaderHelper::setExpires(300);
HeaderHelper::setContentTypeByExtension('json');
ob_start();
echo JsonHelper::encode($return);
craft()->end();
```

but I'd rather use the super convenient `returnJson` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Craft CMS [2.6.2783](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2783), you can pass in an `'expires'` key to the optional `$options` 2nd parameter of [`returnJson`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/BaseController#returnJson-detail) with the value set to the time in seconds that will be passed to the cache control expiration headers.  If you ignore it, it will have the current behavior of not caching at all.

Comment: Thanks Brad! Just saw this in the 2.6.2783 update: https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/BaseController#returnJson-detail